# Spring Security OAuth2 token refreshed by WebClient but stored as "anonymousUser"

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to implement Spring OAuth2 with `WebClient` saving refresh tokens for auto renewal in a `JdbcOAuth2AuthorizedClientService`.

When I first grant access with the Google prompt the token is stored perfectly as a row in the `oauth2_authorized_client` table for the `principal_name` that granted access, let's say john@gmail.com.

Later, when I want to use that stored access_token in a scheduled task (no user interaction) I can fetch it like this and inject it in my `webClient`:

```java
private final OAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService;

// ...

OAuth2AuthorizedClient authorizedClient = authorizedClientService.loadAuthorizedClient("google", "john@gmail.com");

return webClient.get()
                .uri(CALENDAR_URL, uriBuilder -> 
                  uriBuilder.path("/calendars/primary/events")
                            .queryParam("key", API_KEY)
                            .build())
                .attributes(oauth2AuthorizedClient(authorizedClient))
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class);
```

This time the expired token gets automatically renewed (hurray!) but for some reason it is stored in the database table as a new row with `principal_name` as **anonymousUser** instead of john@gmail.com. Why is that?

This is my WebClient configuration:

```java
  @Bean
  public OAuth2AuthorizedClientService oAuth2AuthorizedClientService(JdbcOperations jdbcOperations,
      ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository) {
    return new JdbcOAuth2AuthorizedClientService(jdbcOperations, clientRegistrationRepository);
  }

  @Bean
  public WebClient webClient(ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository, OAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService) {

    AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager manager = new AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(
        clientRegistrationRepository, authorizedClientService);

    manager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(new DelegatingOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider(
        new RefreshTokenOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider(),
        new ClientCredentialsOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider()));

    ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth2 = new ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(
        manager);
    oauth2.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("google");

    return WebClient.builder()
                    .filter(oauth2)
                    .apply(oauth2.oauth2Configuration())
                    .build();
  }
```

Comment: my first guess is that the `SecurityContextHolder` has  an anonymous authentication -which makes sense as your task is Scheduled. you can add the current authentication to it  when you first load it from db

Comment: but if i programatically set the authorized client, why would it access the security context instead?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem today and I ended up creating my own oauth2AuthorizationSuccessHandler to save the token to the correct authorized client in my DB.

Comment: I just ran a test to see if setting the authorization to null in the security context would work, and it does. SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(null) does the trick. It would probably be better to disable anonymous auth all together

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @SamSamTheCoderMan could you expand your answer by adding a code sample?

Comment: @JoaquínL.Robles the solution I landed on was to add http.anonymous(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable) to my SecurityFilterChain Bean. Solved the problem